# Removing HBox terminal output

Tags: python, pandas, output, tqdm, hbox

I convert an excel file to a h5 file with `pandas` and `tqdm`.

Following is reduced version of the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

# read raw table
pd.set_option('io.hdf.default.format', 'table')
store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')

# get original file
original_file = ('test.xlsx')

# tables
table_names = ['A', 'B', 'C']

for name in tqdm(table_names):
    # some pre-process data
    df = pd.read_excel(original_file, sheet_name=name, skiprows=2)
    df.columns = [i.strip() for i in df.columns]
    df.index = pd.date_range('2020-01-01 00:00', periods=len(df.index),
                             freq='H', tz='UTC')
    del df['Date from']
    del df['Date to']

    df.index.name = 'date_time'

    # rename columns
    mapping = {...}
    if 'xxx' in name:
        df = df.rename(columns=mapping)

    # inject table to hdf store
    store[name] = df.copy()
    del df

store.close()

print('H5 file is ready')
```

Above code gives me a weird output like following:

```
HBox(children=(HTML(value=''), FloatProgress(value=0.0, max=9.0), HTML(value='')))

H5 file is ready
```

I am guessing this `HBox` thing is a way of showing the h5-file creation process like a loading bar. However it does not show anything and write this line `...children=(HTML...`. Since it does not give me any information, I would like to remove this `HBox` line. But I am not sure which command above in the script, creates this. Any ideas?

Btw a working progress bar could be also good if it is easy to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HBox` is related to `tqdm.notebook`. so remove `tqdm` in this:

```
 for name in tqdm(table_names):
```

If you want to show progress, you can use usual `tqdm`:

```
from tqdm import tqdm  # not tqdm.notebook
for name in tqdm(table_names):
```

Comment: btw speed of the progress-bar is `27.17s/it`, I am guessing it is seconds/iteration?